# Dimensionality reduction by predominant component analysis

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, image-processing

Does anyone know the concept of dimensionality reduction by **predominant component analysis**?

It was introduced in the following scientific paper: [Grundland & Dodgson, 2005, The decolorize algorithm for contrast enhancing, color to grayscale conversion](http://www.eyemaginary.com/Rendering/TurnColorsGray.pdf), the concept in described in section 4.3.

Could anyone explain how it works?

Comment: With [only 25 hits in Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.pt/scholar?hl=en&q=%22predominant+component+analysis%22) it doesn't seem to be a very well-known technique. I haven never heard of it, but might try to take a look at the paper to see if I can figure out what's it about.

Comment: Thank you Amoeba for checking upon my post. I have been trying to understand this concept from the paper. I was less successful to interpret this concept. I was also trying to understand how does it differ from PCA. I am very eager to know your views. Hope it will be interesting for you too.

I have tried to discuss about this topic with Mr. Grundland and Dr. Neil. Please drop me a mail if possible. I could forward you the dicussion. Email ID. Nrupatunga.tunga@gmail.com